# Cannot access to own hosted gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I've installed gitlab on my own server but I can't access to gitlab's main page , in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` I've setted the following variables

```
external_url 'http://myip:8085/gitlab'
```

and

```
nginx['listen_port'] = 8085
```

If i try to acces to `http://myip:8085/gitlab` the browser doesn't found the 
url , `The connection has timed out`

I've missed something??

Comment: Do you have reconfigured? `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

Comment: Yes , `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and `gitlab-ctl restart`